# Google map works fail in android mobile

Tags: google-maps

Hi i developed gpslocator apps using google api 1.5.. The google map is displaying in emulator....i installed apk file in mobile. but it does not display map. it only shows the grid. is it any api key should be specified for mobile as we did for the system..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll have to use the keytool.  look [here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) for details.

The proccess will give you a key that you need to put in the apiKey field. for example:

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:apiKey="0AHIjblxfiqK2Zq0sDLXmAyMbYMLRdkf4TmiFuQ"
  />
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply.. i already added the above code in my xml page.. i cant access gps in emulator so i took its apk file and installed in mobile. the apps in mobile does not shows anything but simply grid..

Comment: 1. But did you used your key? the key I specified might not work on your device. 2. Did you give the permissions for the app to use GPS?

Comment: ya i used my key.. i generated md5 fingerprint.. i given three of the below permission..  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: what about <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>